# Can I learn the Win32 API without C++ (with only C)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm sorry about asking a weird question about this. I googled and looked up to here for a solution, but none of the answers satisfy what actually I want.

I am really confused about this question. It's been almost 2 years that I have been studying for security based work. So, I have good knowledge about Python and C.

The company that I referred gave me advise to learn about Win32. But when I begin  to learn about it, I encountered that [Win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/introduction-to-windows-programming-in-c--) is C++ based. But I don't want to waste time again to study it. Some blogs talk about Windows Programming in C/C++, and this makes more confusion for me as C and C++ are essentially separate from each other, I think.

My questions are:

1. Can I learn Win32 with only C?
2. If no, then can I learn it over C?
3. If yes, how deep do I have to go (so, all context of it or specific)?

So again sorry. I'm really very confused at the moment that I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: Most Win Api is C. There are couple exceptions (dor example COM IFAIR).

Comment: But almost every code in MSDN says C++..

Comment: @MarekR All the COM APIs are C compatible.

Comment: C/C++ are not almost separate, C can be treated as a subset of C++ while existing differences are result of standardization committees doing poor job. *"don't want to waste again time for studying it"* - but switching to C++ is a must after C.

Comment: Win32 API is primarily C as other people stated. A good book is the old Petzold's Programming Windows 95 book which is about GDI and GUI topics and Richter's 'Advanced Windows' which is more about kernel32.dll stuff. Pretty rare that you hear these days that someone wants to learn Win32

Comment: Thanks for help.I will do it .first glance scared maybe.I dont know

Comment: You should check out [CppCon 2016: Dan Saks “extern c: Talking to C Programmers about C++”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7Sd8A6_fYU)

Comment: @gast128    It's even surprise for me why Win32 api should i learn for security company.And why for i will use it ,  i don't know.

Comment: @Günel Resulova: perhaps good to ask since Win32 API also contains cryptography and account management. That's only a small portion of the Win32 API and the books I mentioned don't cover that.

Comment: You'll need to study C++ regardless if you intend to use it or not. In particular, you need to study object-oriented design. All well-written C programs use many OO aspects. And using C++ specific terminology such as constructors, function overloading etc is helpful for C programmers as well.

Comment: @VTT C/C++ polyglots are *possible* to write, but it's a challenge and the result will just look like crappy C.

Comment: @Fredrik While I somewhat agree that C++ is a bloated mess (actually I consider C quite bloated as well) it offers so many improvements over C that I can not imagine someone working on at least medium sized C codebase not wanting to take advantage of at least some of them.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure what are these "C/C++ polyglots" you are referring to. Perhaps you should check out the video I posted above.

Comment: @VTT a program that compiles and does the same thing in C and C++, written in the common subset of the two languages.

Comment: @Quentin I'd say that a program that compiles and does the same thing in C and C++, written in the common subset of the two languages would be just a normal C program. And writing it won't be that challenging, though definitely time consuming. What is your point anyway?

Comment: @VTT that half the features of C don't exist in C++ or work differently, so C is definitely not a subset of C++.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know - yes, it should be possible. The older Windows APIs were in fact C based and that's what I learned myself 20 years ago. They're quite straightforward. The newer ones are based on COM which is a bit more of a hassle to do in C, but by no means impossible. I remember reading some good tuorials on doing just that (COM in C), although I don't have any handy links to give out I'm afraid.

That said, C and C++ are quite close. In fact, C++ was originally intended to be a superset of C - every valid C program was supposed to be a valid C++ program. Now, they didn't quite make that happen, but the differences are subtle and for the most part shouldn't bother you much. So you might as well continue writing code in C, using just a bit of C++ for interfacing with COM. The C++ compiler should accept this just fine.

Comment: It's not problem links ,I think i get  main question that i can learn it with C.And Codes in MSDN which says C++ can compile with C compiler?

Comment: C and C++ are closely related. Most C programs can be compiled as C++ with little to no changes.